# Java JSoup error: Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException

Tags: java, web, jsoup

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que obtiene las letras de canciones (estoy usando la pagina de genius.com), se que el error que puse en el titulo me da cuando lo que estoy buscando con JSoup "no existe" pero estoy muy seguro que el error está en esta parte: `Element p = doc.select("div.Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-6").get(0);`

"div.Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-6" se supone que es el div donde se guarda la cancion que escogiste (lo estoy viendo con Inspeccionar) ( y si intenté combinarlas: Element p = doc.select("div.Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-6.jYfhrf").get(0);  )

ese div tiene 2 clases: Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-6 y jYfhrf pero ninguna funciona

Imagen del div: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMKhl.jpg

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=http://genius.com/Imagine-dragons-believer-lyrics
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:760)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:757)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
    at main.LyricsGatherer.getSongLyrics(LyricsGatherer.java:21)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Código

```
public class LyricsGatherer {

    private final static String songLyricsURL = "https://www.genius.com";

    public static List<String> getSongLyrics(String author, String songTitle) throws IOException {
        List<String> lyrics = new ArrayList<String>();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(songLyricsURL + "/" + author.replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase() + "-" + 
                songTitle.replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase() + "-lyrics").get();
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println(title);
        Element p = doc.select("div.Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-6").get(0);
        //Element p = doc.select("div.jYfhrf").get(0); este tampoco funciona
        for (Node e : p.childNodes()) {
            if (e instanceof TextNode) {
                lyrics.add(((TextNode) e).getWholeText());
            }
        }
        return lyrics;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que no te de error la petición y te devuelva lo mismo que te devolvería si realizaras la petición desde el navegador, debes incluir el `userAgent`. Por ejemplo:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect( "https://genius.com/Imagine-dragons-believer-lyrics" )
        .userAgent( "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0" )
        .get();

String title = doc.title();
System.out.println( title );

Element p = doc.select( "div.Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-6" ).get( 0 );
System.out.println( p.text() );
```

Que devuelve como salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: obviamente buscando en google "my user agent" para poner el mio verdad? Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Totis ese mismo que te puse te sirve.